# Can't get heroku site updated on custom domain

Tags: godaddy, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have hosayif.com registered at GoDaddy, and I set up a cname for rails.hosayif.com to point to my heroku app at sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com.

I set this up with a previous app, and it worked.  I made a new app, renamed the old one, and then renamed the new one so that it is sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com in hopes of not having to change anything at GoDaddy.

In theory, rails.hosayif.com and sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com should be the same site, but they are not.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just did a DNS lookup: `rails.hosayif.com >> canonical name = sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com.`

```
Non-authoritative answer:
rails.hosayif.com   canonical name = sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com.
sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com canonical name = ar.herokuapp.com.
ar.herokuapp.com    canonical name = argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 107.20.215.233
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 174.129.244.122
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 23.21.103.189
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 50.17.250.204
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 107.20.177.118
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 107.21.208.103
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 174.129.252.230
Name:   argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 23.21.154.16
```

Looks fine to me from a technical standpoint. Visiting http://rails.hosayif.com/, I see:

```
Welcome aboard
You’re riding Ruby on Rails!

Getting started
Here’s how to get rolling:

    Use rails generate to create your models and controllers

    To see all available options, run it without parameters.
    Set up a default route and remove public/index.html

    Routes are set up in config/routes.rb.
    Create your database

    Run rake db:create to create your database. If you're not using SQLite (the default), edit config/database.yml with your username and password.
```

Visiting "http://sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com/" I see:

```
This should not be the default rails index.html page.
```

**In theory, rails.hosayif.com and sharp-meadow-6535.herokuapp.com should be the same site, but they are not. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?**

*Rails may not be listening on the old domain anymore, since its a CNAME or A-record, which is only going to tell it the IP address of the application, and use the "referring domain" to go to your site accordingly. It's supposed to listen only on the new domain, correct?*

So I'd say everything is working.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "listening".  I am very new at making websites/applications.  Is there maybe a link you can send me to that explains what your last paragraph means?

Comment: In general server terminology, "listening" means exactly that. I would say "HEY JOSEPH!" and you'd look at me. If I say "HEY MIKE" then you would ignore it. Servers work the same way, but with domain names.